# how to send user provide shipping address using xml in paypal adaptive payment?

Tags: xml, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

i am using paypal payments in one of my e-commerce website. But when a payment is made successfully it shows that we do not have postal address on file, so it is not secure. I am sending shipping address which user fills at the time checkout. The code i am using to process this request are

```
<PayRequest>
    <requestEnvelope>
         <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
    </requestEnvelope>
    <cancelUrl xmlns="">http://exammple.com/cancelURL.htm</cancelUrl>
    <actionType>PAY</actionType>
    <currencyCode xmlns="">USD</currencyCode>
    <receiverList xmlns="">
         <receiver>
              <amount>100</amount>
              <email>xyz@example.com</email>
              <primary>true</primary>
         </receiver>
         <receiver>
              <amount>75</amount>
              <email>abc@example.com</email>
              <primary>false</primary>
         </receiver>
     </receiverList>
     <returnUrl xmlns="">http://example.com/returnURL.htm</returnUrl>
</PayRequest>
```

This is just sample code. How can i include shipping address in this so it does not show in paypal account that we do not have postal address on file ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run another API operation called [SetPaymentOptions API Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/) with the paykey of Pay API operation for setting the shipping address.